# Как увеличить время видимости полосы прокрути listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Как увеличить время видимости полосы прокрути listview?

Comment: Не надо в метки добавлять JS и AS - они к вопросу не относятся

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10496398/3212712) можно предотвратить исчезание полосы прокрутки чрез атрибут `android:fadeScrollbars`

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

А собственно настроить длительность исчезания полосы прокрутки можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35144589/3212712):

```
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="500"
```

А так - настроить задержку перед стартом анимации исчезновения:

```
android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="1000"
```

Comment: благодарю отлично расписали )